# How can I extrude two faces?

Tags: mesh, faces, extrude, svg

How can i make the hole in the letter

[image: **I would like to make the hole in the letter P**]

Comment: ok, I find out knife projection will work. If anybody got a better solution just tell me

Comment: question is not clear.. extrude two faces? you need to cut out a piece of a plane from the main shape?

Comment: hahaha yeah bro, i was sure it was wrong but did't know what to write

Answer (score 1):

Add a mesh of the cutout(orange piece), enter it in the place want to be cut out, add a boolean modifier to the main mesh(letter),(its already at difference from default), click the eyedropper and select the mesh cutout(orange), apply the modifier and move away the mesh cutout(orange) to get a result you want.

Comment: bro the result is all messed up, the mesh is full of random vertexes

Comment: in OBJECT mode.